# DOMDocument::Load(); error read read of 8192 bytes failed with errno=13 Permission denied

Tags: php, domdocument

I am at an internship right now and got this old 2012 code, I have tried my best to debug it but I can only get this error. I have already tried to increase my PHP limit in php.ini and that did nothing. it also isn't the XML file because I can print the entire thing to the website with no problem. it might be a problem with the file locking since this is the first time I have used it.

this is the PHP

```
    <?PHP
     // First Clear any status messages from CMS
     // Find filepath
     $dir = getcwd();
     $pieces = explode("/", $dir);
     $processname = $pieces[count($pieces) - 1];
     $recmsgfilepath = "savedmsg.default.xml";

     //saved for later use in $recmsgfilepath
     //tmp/webpage/".$processname."/msgfromcms.xml

     // Lock file
     $newmsgfile = fopen($recmsgfilepath, "r+");
     while(!flock($newmsgfile, LOCK_EX))
     {
        // Continue to try to lock file, webserver will eventually terminate PHP script
     } 
     $newmsgdoc = new domDocument();
     if((filesize($recmsgfilepath) > 0) && $newmsgdoc->load($recmsgfilepath))
     {  
        // Clear rec message file
        ftruncate($newmsgfile, 0);
     }
     flock($newmsgfile, LOCK_UN); // release the lock
     fclose($newmsgfile);


     // Check if any buttons pressed

     if(isset($_POST['clearmessages']))
     {
        // Send message to delete all messages in web app
        SendMessage("", "WEBVIEW", "4", "", "", "", "", "");
     }
```

the xml

```
<SAVEDMESSAGES last_changed="16449122918046">
    <TEXTMESSAGE TIMESTAMP="16449122918046" TIMESTAMP_MSG="1644912290" PRIO="0" ALARMID="-">
        <TIME>09:04:50</TIME>
        <DATE>2022-02-15</DATE>
        <ADDRESS></ADDRESS>
        <PRIO>0</PRIO>
        <TIMEOUT>60</TIMEOUT>
        <TEXT>TESTMESSAGE</TEXT>
        <ALERTTYPE>0</ALERTTYPE>
        <CALLBACK></CALLBACK>
        <SENDERID></SENDERID>
        <ALARMINITIATOR>0</ALARMINITIATOR>
        <ACKDATA></ACKDATA>
        <POSINFO1>0</POSINFO1>
        <POSINFO2>0</POSINFO2>
        <RFP0>0</RFP0>
        <STATUS>ORIGINAL</STATUS>
        <ORIGIN>CONFIG</ORIGIN>
        <MESSAGEID>338599</MESSAGEID>
    </TEXTMESSAGE>
</SAVEDMESSAGES>
```

Comment: Is that the complete XML or a tiny fragment from it?

Comment: The problem might not be with your code. The file has permissions as well. Your webserver is likely not allowed to read the document. So add read permissions or give the file to (just guessing) the `www-data` user and group.

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius No sorry, <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?> this is on top of it all.

Comment: @PeterKrebs i have given both the .php and the .XML file full permissions. it sadly did not help